# Raise Unit of Measure type to specificed power

Tags: f#

Is it possible to somehow create a pow function for measure types?
The pow function in f# only takes `int` as parameter, and then pow function in the `Math` class takes a `float` - but dosent allow `float<cm>`.

I first thought that:

```
let rec myPow(x:float<cm>,y:int) =
    if y = 0 then x
    else myPow(x*x, y - 1)
```

might work out, but its obvious that each time it come across the else line it will change the return type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that your code calculates `x^(2^y)`, not `x^y`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ankur is correct - you cannot do this (without resorting to hacks that would break units).

Maybe a clearer description of the problem is that the type of `pow` function would *depend on the value* of the argument and F# doesn't allow you to do this. You could imagine this would work if were using just literals as the second argument, but it would become tricky if you used expressions:

```
pow a 3 // Assuming a = 1.0<cm>, the return type is float<cm ^ 3>
pow a n // Assuming a = 1.0<cm>, the return type is float<cm ^ n>
```

In the second case the value `n` would have to appear in the type!

You can use some nasty tricks (inspired by this [Haskell article](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_arithmetic)), but it becomes a bit crazy. Instead of using numeric literals, you'd use something like `S(S(S(N)))` to represent the number `3`. This way, you can bring the number into the type. You probably don't want to do this, but here is an example:

```
[<Measure>] type cm

// Represents a number with units of measure powered to the
// number's value (e.g "(S (S O))" has type Num<cm, cm^3>)
type Num<[<Measure>] 'M, [<Measure>] 'N> = 
  | O_ of int * float<'N>
  | S_ of int * Num<'M, 'N / 'M>

// Constructors that hide that simplify the creation  
let O : Num<'M, 'M> = O_ (1, 0.0<_>)
let S n = match n with O_(i, _) | S_(i, _) -> S_(i + 1, n)

// Type-safe power function with units of measure
let pow (x:float<'M>) ((O_(i, _) | S_(i, _)):Num<'M, 'M 'N>) : float<'M 'N> =
  // Unsafe hacky implementation, which is hidden
  // from the user (for simplicity)
  unbox ((float x) ** float i)

let res = pow 2.0<cm> (S (S O))
```

**EDIT:** I posted the source code to F# snippets, so that you can see the inferred types: http://fssnip.net/4H

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that is possible. You are asking the function to return `<cm^2>` in case the power is by 2 and `<cm^3>` in case of 3 and so on. Which makes the function to return different "types" based on the calculation which obviously not possible in a static type and type safe language. Unfortunately, I don't think units of measure can be made "generics" to try that to reach any further.

Your function can have only one static return type.

Comment: +1 Your answer is correct - I just added a couple of details to - hopefully - clarify the reason.

Comment: "makes the function to return different "types" based on the calculation which obviously not possible in a static type and type safe language."


You can do this in dependently typed languages like Idris. And it's type-safe and statically typed.

Answer (score 5):

As said, you cannot. If `y` is not known at compile-time, it's not possible to type check the expression in F# type system.

I suspect you'll use myPow only with a few small and known constants. In this case, you could use the following functions instead and keep static typing:

```
let inline pow2 (x: float<'a>) : float<'a^2> = pown (float x) 2 * 1.<_>
let inline pow3 (x: float<'a>) : float<'a^3> = pown (float x) 3 * 1.<_>
let inline pow4 (x: float<'a>) : float<'a^4> = pown (float x) 4 * 1.<_>
let inline pow5 (x: float<'a>) : float<'a^5> = pown (float x) 5 * 1.<_>
```